# Transferring data using Emscripten Worker API without copying

Tags: javascript, c++, c, web-worker, emscripten

Is there a way to get Emscripten to transfer, and not copy, data between web workers and the main UI thread?

Emscripten has an [API that manages communication between Web Workers](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/emscripten.h.html#worker-api), which I believes just uses the [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage) / [`onmessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/onmessage) mechanism under the hood. Looking in the source for the [Emscripten Worker API](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/1edf19d6e3443d5dd6bf366bb41a0cd37191fb20/src/library_browser.js#L1307), it appears that it *doesn't* use the `transferList` option when it calls `postMessage`, and so the data gets copied.

Actually, I think it gets copied at least twice: first by the browser between the threads, and then a [second time by Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/1edf19d6e3443d5dd6bf366bb41a0cd37191fb20/src/library_browser.js#L1276) to get it into the Emscripten-managed heap-space. And if you want the data to continue to survive on the receiving end after the callback, it would have to be copied a third time, as [according to the docs](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/emscripten.h.html#c.emscripten_call_worker) the data passed to the callback is only guaranteed to exist during the callback.

Repeating my question from the top: is there a way to get Emscripten to avoid all this copying by transferring, and not copying, data between web workers and the main UI thread?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if you make use of [SharedArrayBuffer](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NDGA_gZJ7M7w1Bh8S0AoDyEqwDdRh4uSoTPSNn77PFk/edit#heading=h.a6o4dubw5qla). Recently, the Emscripten guys added [experimental support for pthread in Emscripten](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/emscripten-discuss/gQQRjajQ6iY), which use this feature. However, only the Firefox nightly supports SharedArrayBuffers at the moment, so this is not widely adopted yet.